# ember.js and nested templates/views

Tags: templates, ember.js, view

I'm still trying to learn ember.js so please bear with me.

### Objective

I'm currently creating a one page web application.  When the application, the application will do an ajax call which will return a list of numbers lets.  The application will process these numbers and create a div for each of the numbers and store it into a div container.

A click event will be associated with each div, so when the user clicks on the link a pop up dialoge will come up.

### Code

Index.html

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
            {{outlet}}

        </script>

        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="payloads"> 
            <div class="page">
                <div id="desktopWrap">
                    <div id="theaterDialog" title="Theater View" class="bibWindow1">
                            {{view.name}}
                    {{#each item in model}}
                        <div {{bindAttr id="item"}} {{action click item}}>
                            <div class="thumb1" ></div>
                            <div class="userDetails1">Payload {{item}}</div>
                            <div class="online1" ></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="spacer10"></div>
                    {{/each}} 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </script>
```

My app.js file is here:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['Payload_1', 'Payload_2', 'Payload_3'];
  }
});

App.PayloadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
    return ['Payload_1', 'Payload_2', 'Payload_3'];
  } 
})


  App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(
    {
        click: function(e)
        {
            alert("clicked:" + e);

        }
    })
```

### General Idea

The current code above will create the "theaterDialogue" div box with 3 divs.  A onclick action is associated with it through the Controller for each of these divs.  When a user clicks on the first div "payload 1" will be printed in an alert box, second div "payload 2" etc.  Instead of the print out, I want to be able to render a new dialogue box (jquery dialogue box) where the contents will be rendered from a template.  Its not clear to me how this is done.....I understand that views are used to store data for the templates...but not how you would nest a template within one that is generated by an action?

If you could point me anyone, that would be awesome!

Any advice appreciated,
D

Answer (score 6):

Basic approach for nesting is,

- Define the nested routes (Main step, if you get this right, you are almost there)

  Add `{{outlet}}` in the templates if you think that this view will have something appended to it later on

For example we have 3 views A, B, C and the nesting is as follows

```
A
|_B
  |_C
```

Then the templates A & B should have the `{{outlet}}`, while C is the last one it shouldnt have `{{outlet}}`

A good [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qeVGG/)

Comment: I really like this example! +1

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I don't think exactly address what I'm looking for.  In the example you gave, the {{outlet}} will just update the data base on what link is clicked.  However, I want it to all be up at the same time.  Example: User loads page, sees a popup with three divs.  Each div can be clicked and a new popup with new data will be displayed.  A user can close each popup, but you get the general idea.  Also I think I'm not getting the difference between a view and template.  Can a view have multiple templates?

Comment: With the example I just want to give you the basic approach that needs to be taken for nesting, so that you use the understanding to come up with the solution for your use case. regarding a view & template, a view can have only one template, template is nothing but the html content that should go for a particular view, More about views http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/